# how to remote control LED matrix within nearby sealed environment

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, wireless, bluetooth, remote-control

I want to display text on an LED matrix that is located within a sealed environment.  I want to change the text by remote control, by using my iPhone.
Power is available in the environment for electronics.
Environment allows RF.
iPhone would be about 10 feet away.

WiFi or Bluetooth sounds good.
I want to do as little hardware development as possible.
What low power microcontroller will work?  I can program it myself.

How can I do this?

Comment: Bluetooth. Wi-Fi. IRDA. Take your pick.

Comment: Bluetooth/WiFi sounds good.  What is IRDA?

Comment: [Infrared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_Data_Association)

Comment: This question is too broad as there is no specific answer. There are thousands of combinations of microprocessor\wireless modules and dev kits. Just go on digikey and buy any wireless dev kit. Broad questions are usually voted down by the community. For help writing questions see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . That being said use an ESP8266 and go find the tutorials, there are hundreds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have chosen to solve problem using Particle Internet Button which uses Photon Arduino board, with an LED matrix shield.  Photon features WiFi interface for wireless communication to control pattern of LED matrix within sealed environment, from external iPhone/iPad iOS control device.